# How to change sysadmin role for a SQL login to db_owner on all databases using SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a login which has sysadmin server role. I want to change the role to be db_owner on all databases using a sql script. Can someone guide on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the login name is "Rose", this should work (untested)

```
-- Remove login from sysadmin
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropsrvrolemember
     @loginame = 'Rose'
   , @rolename = 'sysadmin'
;
GO

-- [ab]use the undocumented procedure to loop over all databases
EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
  USE [?];

  -- Create the user
  CREATE USER "Rose" FOR LOGIN "Rose";

  -- Assign the db_owner role
  EXEC sp_addrolemember
       @rolename   = ''db_owner''
     , @membername = ''Rose''
  ;
';
```

Give it a quick test before you put it in to production!

Comment: I really would advise staying away from sp_MSForEachDB. It is undocumented, unsupported, and has acknowledged but unresolved bugs (e.g. skipping databases). See [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx) and [this](http://mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201).

Comment: Also, on modern versions of SQL Server, you should use [`ALTER ROLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx) rather than the deprecated [`sp_addrolemember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx).